# covariance error when returning an element of List<DerivedClass>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, covariance

I'm dealing with a problem which is giving me a headhache. I've been reading a few posts about the issues related with covariance and contravariance in C# but anything seems to solve this one.

```
public abstract class BaseImporter<TEntity> : IImporter<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    //don't pay attention to this method
    public TEntity SomeMethodWhichUsesTheGenericType();

    //this is the important one
    protected abstract IBaseReader<IFileData> GetReader(Stream file, params object[] args);
}

public interface IImporter<out T> where T : class
{
    //don't pay attention to this method
    T SomeMethodWhichUsesTheGenericType();
}

public interface IBaseReader<out T> where T : IFileData
{
   T GetFileData(Stream stream);

    bool CanHandleStream(Stream stream, params object[] args);
}

public interface IFileData
{

}
```

Look that I have created a **BaseImporter** abstract class which exposes a method *GetReader()* which returns a **IBaseReader** to a certain **IFileData**. If you look the declaration of IBaseReader it specifies the "***out***" keyword related with covariance concept.

In other assembly, I have declared some classes which make use of these ones.

```
public class JETFileData : IFileData
{
    List<string> Data { get; set; }
}

public class ExcelFileReader : BaseReader<JETFileData>
{
    public override bool CanHandleStream(Stream stream, params object[] args)    
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override JETFileData GetFileData(Stream stream)
    {
        return new JetFileData() { Data = new List<string>() };
    }
}
```

Look that **JETFileData** *is* a **IFileData** and the **ExcelFileReader** is a reader which passing a Stream returns a **JETFileData**

And then I have a concrete Importer derived from **BaseImporter**. e.g.:

```
public class US_ETDocumentImporter : BaseImporter<US_ETDocument>
{
    public List<IBaseReader<JETFileData>> Readers { get; set; }

    public US_ETDocumentImporter()
    {
        this.Readers = new List<IBaseReader<JETFileData>>()
        {
            new ExcelFileReader()
        };   
    }

    //HERE IS WHERE I GOT THE ERROR!!!
    protected override IBaseReader<JETFileData> GetReader(Stream file, params object[] args)
    {
        //decide which reader is able to be used to process this file
        return this.Readers.Single(r => r.CanHandleStream(file, args));
    }
}
```

So, the error says:

```
'Importers.US_ETDocumentImporter.GetReader(System.IO.Stream, params object[])': return type must be 'Core.IBaseReader<Core.IFileData>' to match overridden member 'Core.BaseImporter<Documents.US_ETDocument>.GetReader(System.IO.Stream, params object[])'
```

And an image could be helpful too:
[image]

As I said, I believe that the error is related with covariance, but I am not completely sure. It seems that the compiler doesn't get that **JETFileData** is an **IFileData** I guess.
 What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It doesn't help that you haven't shown us `BaseJETImporter`. Also, I suspect that a lot of the detail here is unnecessary... can you try to reduce this to a short but complete example which contains nothing extraneous? I suspect you *may* need another generic type parameter, but it's hard to tell at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to simplify the problem and that class it is not needed. I will correct it now. Keep in mind that the code is a lot longer... so I tried to make it the more readable as I could.

Comment: It's worth asking yourself for each aspect whether it's required. (Do we need to know about readers? If so, do we actually need to know that they're reading from streams?) Reducing problems to the shortest form is a really good way of focusing on the core of a problem.

Comment: @MauroBilotti: you can't change signature, when overriding a virtual method. This isn't related to covariance at all.

Comment: I thought that it makes easier to understand the scope of the problem against naming everything as "SomeDerivedClass", "AnyMethod" and so on. As you can see I have a lot of classes involved, so maybe if I remove one the solution can be completely different.

Comment: mmm... this is a good point. So am I forced to return as IBaseReader<IFileData>? I can't figure out how to make different implementations of IFileData outside the Core assembly...

Comment: @MauroBilotti Yes, the return types must match exactly when overriding.  C# doesn't currently support return type covariance.

Comment: @MauroBilotti: you're forced to keep *signature* of the method as it declared in base class. The *real* data type of return value, of course, can be a descendant type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this has anything to do with covariance, instead the problem is you're trying to change a return type in an override method.

Change `BaseImporter` to have another generic type, and constrain it to `IFileData`

```
public abstract class BaseImporter<TEntity, TFileData> : IImporter<TEntity> 
      where TEntity : class 
      where TFileData: IFileData
{
        //don't pay attention to this method
        public TEntity SomeMethodWhichUsesTEntity()
        {
            return null;
        }

        // changed IFileData to TFileData
        protected abstract IBaseReader<TFileData> GetReader(Stream file, params object[] args);
}
```

Then, when you override this in `US_ETDocumentImporter` you get exectly what you want:

```
public class US_ETDocumentImporter : BaseImporter<US_ETDocument,JETFileData>
{
    public List<IBaseReader<JETFileData>> Readers { get; set; }

    public US_ETDocumentImporter()
    {
        this.Readers = new List<IBaseReader<JETFileData>>()
        {
            new ExcelFileReader()
        };   
    }

    //HERE IS WHERE I GOT THE ERROR!!!
    protected override IBaseReader<JETFileData> GetReader(Stream file, params object[] args)
    {
        //decide which reader is able to be used to process this file
        return this.Readers.Single(r => r.CanHandleStream(file, args));
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!!! :D it works perfectly.  Thanks a lot! Should I change the title? because for me always was a covariance problem and it wasn't.

Comment: So, the problem was that if you need to change the signature of the method on the derived class, you need to specify a generic type on the base class in order to be changed down.

Comment: As Dennis well said, "you're forced to keep signature of the method as it declared in base class"